# Nested case in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

My sql statement is below:

```
    CASE
        WHEN ((((offr_evnt_sta_cd LIKE 'A%')

             THEN (Coalesce(co_incnt2_amt, label))
```

I have written the spark code below but getting error.

```
sf.when((col('offr_evnt_sta_cd').rlike('^A')) ,sf.when(col('co_incnt2_amt').isNull(),col('label')).otherwise(col('co_incnt2_amt')).alias('ddd')
```

please suggest how can we solve this.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you get an error that you have more arguments (three) than expected (two), and this is correct.

Why not just combine both conditions together, something like this:

```py
sf.when((col('offr_evnt_sta_cd').rlike('^A')) & (col('co_incnt2_amt').isNull()),
        col('label'))\
    .otherwise(col('co_incnt2_amt')).alias('ddd')
```

SparkByExamples has very [good description of `when` function](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-when-otherwise/)

Comment: kindly help me how to include one more when condition with above code.

Comment: use `&` for `and` operation, and `|` for `or` operation

Comment: WHEN ((((offr_evnt_sta_cd LIKE 'A%')

             THEN (Coalesce(co_incnt2_amt, label)
WHEN ((((offr_evnt_sta_cd LIKE 'P%')
OR       (offr_evnt_sta_cd LIKE 'R%') 
             THEN (Coalesce(co_incnt2_amp, label2)

Comment: please help to make the spark code..when i mm using another otherwise..its showing error:otherwise() can only be applied once on a Column previously generated by when()

Comment: can you describe in words what you want to achieve? or via `if ... then ... else...`

Comment: i want to achieve: if col_1=5 and col_2=3 then (if 5< (when col_6=4 then col_7 else col_8) then col_9)

Answer (score 0):

I usually break down my transformation and chained functions this way to keep track of parentheses and syntax. Don't forget to wrap your multiline transformation code inside a parenthesis, otherwise, Python will complain.

```py
df.withColumn('test', sf
    .when(col('offr_evnt_sta_cd').rlike('^A'), sf
          .when(col('co_incnt2_amt').isNull(), col('label'))
          .otherwise(col('co_incnt2_amt'))
          .alias('ddd')
    )
    .otherwise(...)
    .alias('ddd')
)
```